# How to capture variable number of arguments in lambda function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

I tried the following code but doesn't compile.

```
template <class T, class... A>
void tpool::enqueue(T&& func, A&&... args) {
    std::function<void()> task([func, args] () {
        //...
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the ellipses. Per paragraph 5.1.2/23 of the C++11 Standard:

> A capture followed by an ellipsis is a pack expansion (14.5.3). [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> template<class... Args>
> void f(Args... args) {
>     auto lm = [&, args...] { return g(args...); };
>     lm();
> }
> ```
>
> —*end example* ]

Note: Interestingly enough, GCC is refusing to compile this (see the [live example](http://ideone.com/C2wHot)):

```
template <class T, class... A>
void foo(T&& func, A&&... args) {
    std::function<void()> task([func, args...] () {
        //...
    });
}
```

But considering the above example from the Standard, this is definitely a compiler issue.

Comment: Amazing, do you hold in memory the whole standard or just do a quick look?

Comment: Looks like this gcc bug: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=41933 (your quote was a rather late addition to the standard)

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Oh, interesting. Thank you for the information! Not sure if that's related, but [this](http://ideone.com/CDwlh4) also fails to compile...

Comment: I assume it is the same issue (the capture is just implicit), but if you have a doubt, feel free to add a small testcase to that bug report (that might also remind people that the bug is still there). And don't hesitate to report other bugs when you find them.

Comment: @MarcGlisse fyi: both compile find under clang (llvm 3.2).

Answer (score 3):

When you use `args` in the capture, you need ellipsis:

```
template <class T, class... A>
void tpool::enqueue(T&& func, A&&... args) {
    std::function<void()> task([func, args...] () {
        //...
    });
}
```

Comment: I've tried your code but doesn't compile again. I get the following error: `error: expected ',' before '...' token` `error: expected identifier before '...' token` `error: parameter packs not expanded with '...'`

Comment: @MarcoPacini Are you using GCC? In that case there seems to be a bug in the compiler (as in the [answer by Andy Prowl](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16527660/440558)).

Comment: Yes, I use GCC 4.7.2 installed with macport.

Comment: Same issue with G++ 4.8.4. The G++ ticket appears to hint that a resolution is planned for the 4.9 time-frame.